# ¿Cómo creo una variable a partir de otra usando ifelse?

Tags: r, if, bucle-for, data

Tengo una variable `X` y otra `Y`, y quiero construir una variable `Z` con un condicional considerando los valores contenidos en `X` e `Y`. Esta sería un ejemplo del df:

```
VariableX   VariableY        VariableZ
1                              
2
3
4
5            35
6            42                                
7            54
8            62
```

Para crear la variable `Z`, debo construir un condicional de tal manera que cuando `VariableY` contenga un dato, lo tome y lo ponga en `variableZ`. De lo contrario (cuando no tenga dato), que tome el dato que haya en `VariableX` y lo ponga en `VariableZ`, pero no tengo ni idea de cómo se hace, de cómo se indican las cosas.

```
VariableZ<-if (VariableY=="DatoY"){
"DatoY"}
}else
"Dato de variableX"{
```

La idea es tener un df final así

```
VariableX   VariableY        VariableZ
1                                1
2                                2 
3                                3
4                                4
5            35                  35
6            42                  42            
7            54                  54
8            62                  62
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada, armamos un ejemplo como el que indicas:

```
df <- data.frame(VariableX = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                 VariableY = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,35,42,54,62))

df

  VariableX VariableY
1         1        NA
2         2        NA
3         3        NA
4         4        NA
5         5        35
6         6        42
7         7        54
8         8        62
```

Nota: Entiendo que se trataría de una estructura tipo matriz tal como has dibujado los datos, los valores vacíos en R se individualizan como `NA` (not available/no disponible).

Para resolver tu pregunta, podemos usar la función vectorizada [`ifelse()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html) de la siguiente forma:

```
df$VariableZ <- ifelse(is.na(df$VariableY), df$VariableX, df$VariableY)
df

  VariableX VariableY VariableZ
1         1        NA         1
2         2        NA         2
3         3        NA         3
4         4        NA         4
5         5        35        35
6         6        42        42
7         7        54        54
8         8        62        62
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!!!!!

Comment: Ahora quiero dar la orden de que si algún dato de VariableX están en Variable Y SIN IMPORTAR LA POSICIÓN entonces VariableZ=NA, ¿Cómo lo hago?. Ahora encuentro en mi fichero de datos que hay datos contenidos en la variable X, fila 4, que son los mismos de la variableY pero de la fila 15 por ejemplo. No sé si me entiendas o si prefieres que edite la pregunta.

Comment: @Caro, para lo que me comentas deberías hacer una nueva pregunta, no modificar la actual ya que entonces cambiaría completamente el sentido de cualquier respuesta que hayas recibido, además, editar un pregunta ya respondida le quita mucha "visibilidad" a la misma.

Answer (score -4):

Primero debes tener 3 cosas, 2 arreglos (X, Y) y 1 variable (Z), segundo llenas los arreglos X y X con sus valores respectivamente, luego creas un contador para recorrer los dos arreglos y empieza a decir (por ejemplo) "la posición 1 del arreglo Y, esta vacía? si la respuesta es falsa entonces Z es igual al valor de la posición 1 del arreglo Y, en cambio si la respuesta es verdadera y la posición 1 del arreglo Y esta vacía entonces Z es igual a la posición 1 del arreglo X. Luego sigues con la posición 2, la posición 2 del arreglo Y esta vacía? si la respuesta es falsa entonces Z es igual al valor de la posición 2 del arreglo Y, en cambio si la respuesta es verdadera y la posición 2 del arreglo Y esta vacía entonces Z es igual a la posición 2 del arreglo X. Esto es solo un ejemplo, espero haberme dado a entender. Suerte!!